# A cron job substitute?

Tags: php, cron

I'm in the middle of an installation of Boonex's Dolphin 7. It requires me to set up a cron job that will run every 1 minute. However, my hosting provider allows me to run crons once every 30 minutes minimum. I have used CMSs that have a substitute for that - a script that replaces cron. Is there such a script that I can use for dolphin? .. a name or a link would be nice.

Comment: Of course it's not your fault but I wonder what terribly important tasks such CMS needs to do that cannot wait 30 minutes...

Comment: I wonder too.. I've set it on 30 minutes and I guess I'll find out what's so important soon enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a high traffic page, you could try using PHP PsuedoCron (http://www.bitfolge.de/?l=en&s=pseudocron) which uses the high traffic page to run PHP scripts. It supports crontab style scheduling and has worked out as a quick fix for shared hosting in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Is that cronjob essential for the application? Otherwise, 30 minutes is also ok

Comment: I have no idea what the cron is for. Dolphin is a social networking CMS so it might be important..

Answer (score 1):

> It requires me to set up a cron job that will run every 1 minute

Then go find a different program to do the same job. This the wrong way to solve **any** problem, and hints at very poor programming practices.