# retrive data from DB(MySql) every 1 min

Tags: php, ajax

In my php project, there is table data which need to be updated automatically every 1 min. Thus, the **php file have to get data every 1 min from DB never stop**.

Is there anyone has idea how to solve this kind of problem? I just need basic idea and providing code snippet would be really appreciated.

Comment: crontab is what you are look for to automate an execution of the php script every minute in server side. if you are using ajax, which is the user-end, that's mean you are expecting user to turn on his browser for 24/7.(unless you are looking to return results when user is active only)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459097/a-cron-job-substitute

Answer (score 1):

Use a cron job (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron )

Answer (score 1):

> which need to be updated...every 1 min

The requirement is most likely flawed; while this pattern crops up frequently, in every case I've looked at in detail it has arisen due to a design fault which has created artificial dependencies.

Since, as I've said this crops up frequently, the question has been asked and answered several times on SO and elsewhere. e.g. [A cron job substitute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459097/a-cron-job-substitute) however IME, there is a significant amount of jitter in cron (which varies massively depending on implementation and workload) which is likely to affect a job running with this frequency. You don't say what tolerance there is on the interval. Assuming that the premise is valid then a daemon is likely to be a lot more precise than a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using cron jobs, but in case you don't have that option, a dirty method would be to use set_time_limit to let your script survive past the maximum execution time of your hosting provider.
See http://www.php.net/set_time_limit for details.
Note that this does not work when safe_mode is on, which is the case for some/most of the cheap hosting providers.